# How to update data from database in textfields form in asp.net using vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to edit profile which consists of data from db. What I have tried is:

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConStr").ConnectionString
Dim con As New SqlConnection(constr)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim Query As String = "select * from intadmin_user where" _
                             & "id = @id"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idTxtBox.Text)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = Query
        cmd.Connection = con

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While sdr.Read()
                idTxtBox.Text = sdr("id").ToString()
                usernameTxtbox.Text = sdr("username").ToString()
                pwTxtBox.Text = sdr("password").ToString()
                emailTxtBox.Text = sdr("email").ToString()
                nameTxtBox.Text = sdr("name").ToString()
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Dim query As String = "update intadmin_user set password = '" & pwTxtBox.Text & "' , email = '" & emailTxtBox.Text & "' , name = '" & nameTxtBox.Text & "' where id = '" & idTxtBox.Text & "'"
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = query
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SuccessMsg.Text = "User Profile information has been successfully updated!"
        ErrorMsg.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is my load form and button property for update.

The problem I'm having is that the data is not displayed in the textfields form.

Comment: Hi, my friend. The query has returned the data? You can use debug to check it.

Comment: @Tomato32 , I used break to check. but it executes Throw ex.. which I think my sql is not correct..

Comment: Yeah. I guess so, maybe you should add blank space in "select * from intadmin_user where id =@id". Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Thank you for the help @Tomato32 :) What I did was adding session for id in the website